# Is it possible to detect that sound source is playback of a recording?

Tags: audio, speech-recognition

I have been trying to find an article where it is described how real-time (or close to real-time) signal processing from a microphone is able to detect that an audio source is playback of a recording rather than natural source thanks to (for example) missing frequencies in lossy encoding. Ideally it would be something about voice authentication tampering / voice assistant trigger words filtering. I am sure there is lots on the subject, however I am quite new to the field and can't seem to be able to come up with the right keywords for my googling.

Thanks

Comment: Frank Sinatra is dead, so if a speaker id algorithm identifies Frank Sinatra, its recorded.  My point is that it iis doubtful that a single solution exists for every case.  You could search on LP or tape artifacts and perhaps solve part of the problem, but a recording from a well mastered CD would require a different approach

Comment: There is a whole lot of research going on in the field of speaker identity verification which tackles a problem of someone playing back the recording of the speech. I will add an answer later on with few approaches as I am away from home right now.